# as3 - reusing a loaded image in an 'asset' swf with no control over the loading 'main' swf

Tags: actionscript-3, scope, loading

This is a relatively convoluted problem to explain so please bear with me.

I have a **main.swf** which I cannot control nor recompile. It loads a skin from **skin.swf** which contains all the movie clips and gfx to be used within main.swf.

After **main.swf** being locked down it was decided that **skin.swf** should also be able to load an image as a background to be used in one of the movie clips.

This works fine so far - **main.swf** loads **skin.swf** and uses **frontscreen movieclip** which loads **background.png**

Now I have been asked to use the **background.png** in other movie clips within **skin.swf** and I cant figure out how to expose it to them for use.

A terrible solution would be to load it in each time as I currently do in **frontscreen movieclip** but that is obviously a no no. Alternatively I have considered dynamically ataching it to the **main.swf** but I can't quite figure this out.

Any help on this convoluted mess would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are loading some image with `Loader`. Content is `Bitmap` which you can use on stage in one place. Now you need a copy? If so, load it from bytes of `BitmapData`, it is fast.

Comment: I understand the concept of copying an image based movieclip or sprite using bitmap data. Unfortunately it is more the scope of where to store the loaded data so it can then be recieved based on the setup above - one un-changeable main swf loading an asset swf and using its library items.

Comment: "Now I have been asked to use the background.png in other movie clips within skin.swf and I cant figure out how to expose it to them for use. " Use a copy for them... store that copy in skin.swf.